# Implementing forward-backward/Baum-Welch as in Jurafsky + Martin, 2nd Edition

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp

I'm implementing the forward-backward/Baum-Welch algorithm, as presented in Jurafsky + Martin's *Speech and Language Processing* (2nd Edition), as a part-of-speech tagger.  My code is roughly structured as follows:

```py
#Initialize transition probability matrix A and observation likelihood matrix B
(A,B) = init() #Assume this is correct

#Begin forward-backward/Baum-Welch algorithm
for training_sentence in training_data:
    (A,B) = forward_backward(A,B,training_sentence, vocabulary, hidden_state_set)

#Use new A,B to test
i = 0
for test_sentence in test_data:
    predicted_tag_sequence = viterbi(test_sentence, vocabulary, A,B)
    update_confusion_matrix(predicted_tag_sequence, actual_tag_sequences[i])
    i += 1
```

My implementation initializes A and B before any calls to forward_backward.  Then, the A,B used for each iteration of forward_backward are the A,B calculated from the previous iteration.

There are 2 problems I've been seeing:

1. After the first iteration, A and B are so sparse that future iterations of forward_backward do no expectation maximization steps.
2. The final A and B are so sparse that when applying Viterbi, every word is just assigned some arbitrary tag (since A and B are so sparse the probability of nearly any sequence of tags on the sentence is 0).

What could I be doing wrong?  My biggest concern is theoretical:  Am I correct in calling forward_backward with the A,B from the previous iteration?  Or should I use my initial A,B for all iterations of forward_backward take my final A,B as the average the results?  If my code is fine theoretically, what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

No,  you should not be updating the A and B matrices after each sentence; A and B should only be updated once for each pass over the training data.  You should use the previous iteration's A and B to calculate partial counts from each sentence, and then sum those counts to get the new A and B for next next pass over the data.

The procedure should be:

1. Initialize A and B
2. For each sentence, compute expected counts using forward-backward
3. Sum up the expected counts to get the next A and B
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a numerical issue. In your `forward_backward` you are probably multiplying a whole bunch of small numbers together, which eventually makes the product smaller than the machine precision. If that is the case, you can try working with logs. You should add the logs of probabilities together instead of multiplying the 'raw' probabilities.

Comment: Ok, I'll definitely consider this.  I think my bigger concern was more theoretical:  is my code correct in using the A,B from the previous iteration?  Or should I use the same A,B for each call to forward_backward and average the results? (Will edit original post.)